# How to design Priority search trees

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am looking to implement a tree with the following properties.

1. Should be binary search trees
2. Should be priority tree - that elements with higher priority should be closer to the root.
3. When tree is iterated, all elements with higher priority are traversed first, then all elements with next lower priority...
4. Should be Balanced.
5. Insert/Delete/Update operation should be O(logn)

I know, the tree should exhibit the properties of binary search tree and Heap, and that's what we call as **Priority trees**. But, i am not able to design it which satisfy all above properties, neither i could find clean matter on this on internet.

Comment: That's a tall order, e.g. 2 and 4 seem to be in direct conflict.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
  Most of all, show your work so far.

Comment: Is there a specified iteration order for elements that have the same priority?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to satisfy all the properties at the same time.

Say I have the values [1, 2, 3... 10] with priority equal to the value.
If you want properties 1, 2 and 3, then the only choice is a left only tree starting at 10. That's obviously not balanced. Operations will be O(N).

If you want balance then you need to move the root to something other than 10, but then you break property 3.